# "this" keyword in arrow function behaves diffrently in object literal and in instantiation of a class

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions

```
const myO = {
  myf: () => {
    console.log(this);
  },
};

myO.myf();   // this === window
```

In  object literal, this refers to window;

```
class MyObject {
  myf = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
}
const myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.myf();   //  this === MyObject
```

In an object instantiated from a class, this refers to the object.

Why is the difference?

Question is marked as duplicated but I really can't see any resemblance

Comment: “What this means in simpler terms is that the arrow function *retains the `this` value from its context* and does not have its own this..” — that’s the relevant bit from the accepted answer in the duplicate. When assigned in the class, `this` is different in the scope.

Comment: I’ve voted to re-open because this comes down to the context of `this` in a specific (class syntax) context, which might be overlooked / not expected.

Comment: I understand that an arrow function dose not bind "this" to anything and the scope of "this" is inherited from its lexical environment. So I want to know why in the 2nd case "this" is bound to the object. Does it has something to do with the instantiation process?

Comment: Well, the value of `this` should answer that question.. when the object literal is created the scope of `window` (global). However, *inside the class keyword/definition..*

Comment: Then the *actual question, which would not be a duplicate of the current close target,* might be “What is the scope of assigning to a property inside a class definition?” (Which is entirely separate from the first construct, and only an extension of the behavior of the “understood” arrow function binding, which *is a duplicate* of the linked question.)

Comment: That's indeed what I want to ask. Thanks.